# What players do support flac files with embeded cue sheet?

Tags: software-recommendation, music, encoding, music-player

I recently got some FLAC files with embeded cue sheet. Though, the info of the sheet file doesn't seem to show up in Rhythmbox; Banshee; Amarok or Audatious. Which media players support this kind of file?

Comment: this is an old question and the before-mentioned players might already support this. please comment if so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xmms2 suite of software supports this partially.  You must extract the cuesheet

`metaflac --export-cuesheet-to=myfile.cue myfile.flac`

and then you can do

`nyxmms2 addpls myfile.cue`

flactag also has support for creating the cuesheets and embedded tags in batch mode)

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try [DeaDBeef](http://deadbeef.sourceforge.net/). It's open source and has been ported to Android.
It's the closest thing to foobar2000, even in terms of GUI style.

Answer (score 1):

It is perhaps not the answer you would to ear.

There is a Windows player that supports that, and it works well under Wine. It is [foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the answer for your question, but it gives you more choice: You can use [trackfs](https://github.com/andresch/trackfs) to mount your FLAC+CUE files and then use any media player that supports FLAC.